# How to find out if an Object is a collection or single value?

Tags: apex, soql, dynamic-soql

I have some dynamic SOQL code in which I'd like to identify whether a method argument is a collection or a single value:

```
SObject[] query(SObjectType sobType, String field, Object data) {
    // Want to know if data is a collection e.g. set or list
    // that requires an "in" or a single value that requires
    // an "=" in the query. (May also need to use separate bind variables.)
}
```

I note that the sort of check shown immediately below seems to require an exact match for the type of the collection (`Id` in this case to return true) which is not what I want:

```
Object o = new Set<Id>();
System.debug(o instanceof Set<Id>);
```

Is there a simple way to make this determination?

(Yes there are various other ways to code this; checking first to see if there is a direct solution.)

**PS**

Looks like great caution is needed when using [instanceof with collections](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/106068/apex-string-instanceof-object#125891).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you are using a data binding, you do not need to know. `=` will work in either case, so you don't need to ever switch to `IN` for the use case you outline above. I used the following code in `Execute Anonymous` to demonstrate:

```
Object searchTerm = new Set<String> { 'test', 'test2' };
SObjectField field = Account.Name;
SObjectType sObjectType = Account.sObjectType;

system.debug(Database.query(
    'SELECT Id FROM ' + sObjectType + ' WHERE ' + field + ' = :searchTerm'
));
```

I also used `searchTerm = 'test';` and the query ran just fine in either case.

Comment: Perfect - just what I need. Requiring "in" was a bad assumption on my part. (For completeness I wonder if there is a good answer to the title of the question but I don't need it right now given your approach.)

Comment: I too thought that `IN` was required for collections. I'd +1 again if I could.

Answer (score 12):

Another alternative might be this:

```
public static Boolean isCollection(Object input)
{
    Object test;
    try{
       test = (List<Object>)input;
       return true;
    }
    catch(System.TypeException ex){}
    return false;
}
```

This should work for any `Object`.  Note that this does not work for `Sets` or `Maps`, which both return conversion errors regardless.  You could also modify it to the following:

```
public static Boolean isCollection(Object input)
{
    Object test;
    try{
       test = (List<Object>)input;
       return true;
    }
    catch(System.TypeException ex)
    {
        String message = ex.getMessage();
        return message.contains('Set<') || message.contains('Map<');
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: pretty clever -- debug log gets littered with exceptions though

Comment: Sneaky - one to remember.

Comment: Using exceptions for flow control like this is generally a code smell, and should be avoided, but I still think this one is the best of the solutions to the letter of the question.

Comment: Are you sure it actually works with `Set` or `Map` when the type is concrete? I'm 90% certain that will fail.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Just tested it, it looks like you are right.

Comment: @IllusiveBrian I did a small collection of tests, and basically proved that map, set, and lists are fundamentally type-broken. See [apex String instanceof Object?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/106068).

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to determine whether an `Object` instance is a collection of primitives, it would be a somewhat inelegant `||` chain:

```
public static Boolean isCollection(Object input)
{
    return input instanceof Set<String> || input instanceof List<String> ||
         input instanceof Set<Id> || input instanceof List<Id> ||
         input instanceof Set<Date> || input instanceof List<Date> ||
         input instanceof Set<Datetime> || input instanceof List<Datetime> ||
         input instanceof Set<Decimal> || input instanceof List<Decimal> ||
         input instanceof Set<Integer> || input instanceof List<Integer> ||
         input instanceof Set<Double> || input instanceof List<Double> ||
         input instanceof Set<Long> || input instanceof List<Long>;
}
```

You could add a few more `instanceof` checks, but it's unclear how sensical they would be, for example `Set<Boolean>`, `List<Boolean>`, `Set<SObject>`, `List<SObject>`, etc.

Comment: Yep inelegant especially as in this context it might be a collection of one of dozens of SObject types not the limited set of primitives.

Comment: How would you use a single `SObject` in a filter? I can't see how that's relevant here, but you could check List<SObject> also.

Comment: The `data` argument might be e.g. a `List<Account>` (with `field` being 'AccountId') where the query is looking for all the child `Contact` objects.

Comment: Mind you, if they simply fixed their instanceOf nonsense, we could actually just do `return o instanceof set<object> || o instanceof list<object> || o instanceof map<object, object>;` However, until they choose to fix that problem, we're kind of stuck.

Comment: Same root cause for why @IllusiveBrian's answer did not work.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
Json.serialize(data).startsWith('[')

Object collection = new List<String>{};
Object singleton  = '[';

system.debug(logginglevel.info,json.serialize(collection) + '\n' + Json.serialize(singleton));
```

produces:

```
[]
"["
```

Comment: Think this might be towards the last resort end of the spectrum, particularly if the collection is large so that the JSON creation is a lot of work...

Comment: @KeithC yes, I agree -- more of a theoretical solution than robustly practical