# Is IN operator equivalent to Equal operator in SOQL when binding a list variable?

Tags: soql, dynamic-soql, bind-variable

While testing some SOQL queries I noticed that the Equal operator behaves like the IN operator when using a list bind variable

All the queries below run without any error and return the same result

```
List<String> accNames=new List<String>{'Acme Corporation','Smith Enterprises'};
System.debug('Dynamic Query bind list with Equal operator :'+Database.query('select Name from account where Name = :accNames'));
System.debug('Static Query bind list with Equal operator :'+[select name from account where name = :accNames]);
System.debug('Dynamic Query bind list with IN operator :'+Database.query('select Name from account where Name in :accNames'));
System.debug('Static Query bind list with IN operator :'+[select name from account where name in :accNames]);
```

---

Debug

> DEBUG|Dynamic Query bind list with Equal operator :(Account:{Name=Acme Corporation, Id=0010Y00000E7whoQAB}, Account:{Name=Smith Enterprises, Id=0010Y00000E7wXsQAJ})
>   DEBUG|Static Query bind list with Equal operator :(Account:{Name=Acme Corporation, Id=0010Y00000E7whoQAB}, Account:{Name=Smith Enterprises, Id=0010Y00000E7wXsQAJ})
>   DEBUG|Dynamic Query bind list with IN operator :(Account:{Name=Acme Corporation, Id=0010Y00000E7whoQAB}, Account:{Name=Smith Enterprises, Id=0010Y00000E7wXsQAJ})
>   DEBUG|Static Query bind list with IN operator :(Account:{Name=Acme Corporation, Id=0010Y00000E7whoQAB}, Account:{Name=Smith Enterprises, Id=0010Y00000E7wXsQAJ})

Are the `IN` and `=` operators equal when using a list bind variable?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, `=` and `IN` operators are functionally equivalent when filtering against a list. It is not well covered in the `Force.com SOQL and SOSL Reference` for [Comparison Operators](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_comparisonoperators.htm), but the operators are interchangeable as far as I have observed, if the bind variable is a `List`.

One notable exception is when using a [`Left Inner Join`](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com#Left_Inner_Join), where only `IN` will work.

**Valid**

```
SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Id IN (SELECT ProfileId FROM User)
```

**Invalid**

```
SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Id = (SELECT ProfileId FROM User)
```

See also: [How to find out if an Object is a collection or single value?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/130631/2995)