# Map with the Id and RecordType does not works

Tags: apex

The below query works fine where setCaseId='hds88899889':

```
SELECT Id, DeveloperName FROM RecordType WHERE SObjectType ='Case' AND Id = :setCaseId
```

When I used it below not sure always results into no values

```
Set<Id> setCaseRTId = new Set<Id>();
for(case c : newCases) {  
    setCaseRTId.add(c.recordTypeId); 
} 
Map<Id, RecordType> caseMap = new Map<Id, RecordType>([ SELECT Id, DeveloperName
                                    FROM RecordType WHERE SObjectType ='Case' AND Id = :setCaseRTId]);
System.debug('Map Values ? : '+caseMap);
```

Comment: Are the values all `null`? What do you actually get as the output of `setCaseRTId`?

Comment: setCaseRTId is comming with values which is correct

Comment: No need to use `SobjectType='Case'`, because Id values are always unique.

Comment: Looks like you need an IN in your query.  `AND Id IN :setCaseRTId`

Comment: @JRiffe Actually [the filter works either way](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/130631/2995).