# SOQL Query Where Id "In" Versus "Equals"(=)

Tags: apex, soql

I just stumbled upon a soql query where somebody did the following

```
List<String> names = new List<String>{'John', 'Moe', 'Jeanette', 'Tony'};

List<Client__c> clients = [
    SELECT Id
    FROM Client__c
    WHERE First_Name__c = :names
];
```

I am not familiar with the usage of the equal sign(=) to check against a list/set as opposed to `WHERE First_Name__c IN :names`.

I am having a hard time finding the difference as it seems like using `=` works similarly but does it work the same way? Are there any dangers to using it?

Comment: Note: this special behavior is not available in any API; it only works in Apex code.

Comment: @sfdcfox Can you provide an example if you don't mind? What API would this not work in?

Comment: Any of them. For example, in the Apex Data Loader, you cannot say `select name from lead where name = ('john doe','jane doe')`. This is one of the few magic behaviors of SOQL in Apex.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've not seen a difference functionally; I strongly prefer using IN as that is what would be required in SQL, and it it more accurate, and more descriptive.

First_Name__c is not logically equal to a list.

Using the syntax `First_Name___c IN :names` makes it clear that *names* is a collection, and that the developer knows that it's a collection

Answer (score 3):

They are functionally equivalent. I agree with Mike that `IN` is more syntactically clear, but either one works.

See also: [How to find out if an Object is a collection or single value?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/130631/2995)

This equivalence can be quite useful when building dynamic SOQL.