# Unexpected difference using List<sObject> vs using Set<sObject>

Tags: list, sobject, set, polymorphism

I have sets of objects CustomObjectA, CustomObjectB, CustomObjectC... that I need to pass to a method.

I would like to put them in a Map of type Map< String, Set< sObject > >, but when I try, I get an error:

> Incompatible types since an instance of `Set<CustomObjectA>` is never an instance of `Set<sObject>`.
>
> Incompatible types since an instance of `Set<CustomObjectB>` is never an instance of `Set<sObject>`.

When I change it to lists instead of a sets (using `Map<String, List<sObject>>`) and lists of my custom objects, I don't encounter the same problem.

Why would that occur?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I explained a bit in [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/106068) that collection type casting is broken. You can't use `Set<ConcreteSObjectType>` if you want to be dynamic, so you'll have to settle for adding the records directly to a `Set<SObject>` instead.