# What's the best way to initialize a list of strings in Apex?

Tags: apex

I have a **Map<String, Object> idCollection**.

```
Object accountIdObject = idCollection.get('accountId');
```

Doing this gets me a single string value. Now I am sure that accountIdObject is a String and have a requirement to add it to a **List<String> accountId**

Something like this is easily possible in java which would assign the single string to a new list -

```
List<String> accountId = Arrays.asList((String)accountIdObject);
```

What would be the best way for such initialization in apex ?

I have tried -
`List<String> accountId = new List<String>{(String)accountIdObject}`;
which is giving an exception **Illegal assignment from Object to List**. Also I am sure that accountIdObject contains a string value which I have confirmed by doing a `accountIdObject instanceof String` which returned true.

Comment: What else would be in this map? Will the values of the map ever be something other than strings? Is the plan that this `List` would only have more than one value? Or should it only have one value?

Comment: @Nicholas The map would either return a single string or a list of strings. In case it's a single string, I just want to add it to the accountId list and in case it's a list of strings then simply assign that value to accountId.  Something like - List<String> accountId = accountIdObject instanceof String ? new List<String>{(String)accountIdObject} : accountIdObject; But this gives an exception "Illegal assignment from Object to List."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The long form of what you want looks like:

```
Object accountIdObject = idCollection.get('accountId');
String[] idValues;
if(accountIdObject instanceOf String) {
  idValues = new List<String> { (String)accountIdObject };
}
if(accountIdObject instanceOf List<String>) {
  idValues = (List<String>)accountIdObject;
}
```

Given your example code, the condensed version looks like:

```
List<String> accountId = accountIdObject instanceof String
   ? new List<String>{(String)accountIdObject} 
   : (List<String>)accountIdObject;
```

When using instanceOf, be aware of the limitations outlined in [this post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/106068/2984). If it's not a literal `List<String>`, but some other type that's closely related, you may experience runtime errors.

Comment: The short form is what I was trying but looks like I had missed typecasting in the else part - (List<String>)accountIdObject and kept thinking that something is wrong with the assignment in the if part. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

I'd argue that, based on the name of the map key you're using, you should be generating a `List<Id>` rather than a `List<String>`

In either case, initializing a collection (Map, Set, or List) in Apex is possible by using curly braces.

`List<Id> accountIdsList = new List<Id>{(Id)accountIdObject};`

Multiple values are comma separated

`List<String> myStrings = new List<String>{'a', 'b', 'c'};`

And Maps in particular use "key => value" syntax

```
Map<String, Integer> stringToIntMap = new Map<String, Integer>{
    'a' => 1,
    'b' => 2,
    'c' => 3
};
```

Comment: I am sure that accountIdObject contains a value of type string even though the name suggests otherwise.  I have also confirmed that by doing accountIdObject instanceof String which returns true. I am trying List<String> accountId = new List<String>{(String)accountIdObject} is giving an exception "Illegal assignment from Object to List<String>"