# Enable Map type to hold Integer, String, Boolean, Map, List... objects? (But not generic Object)

Tags: apex, json, class, object, deserialize

I'm attempting deserialize a list of a custom object in Apex, but got an error:

```
FATAL_ERROR System.JSONException: Apex Type unsupported in JSON: Object
```

This is because my ContactPostBack class contains the contact Map with <String, Object> which is not deserializable. Only the listed types here (bottom of page) can be deserialized:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.234.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_collections_maps.htm

```
private String url;
private Map<String, String> headers = new Map<String, String>();
private Map<String, Object> contact = new Map<String, Object>();
```

Changing the declaration of contact to Map<String, String> works, but Integers, Booleans, or other more complicated data structures will simply be converted to strings or throw errors.

**I'd like the contact Map to contain multiple objects, like String, Integer, Boolean, or even other Maps or Lists.** (I'm constructing a JSON object to post different endpoints).

*Is it possible to create a "wrapper class" that contains the data types I can use?*

*Or is there a different implementation of JSON.deserialize that works for Object?*

(Edit) - Included more code where the deserialization happens:

The ContactPostBack object:

```java
public class ContactPostBack {

    private String url;
    private Map<String, String> headers = new Map<String, String>();

    // This only works when: Map<String, String> contacts ...
    // and the other references are changed to Map<String, String> type
    private Map<String, Object> contact = new Map<String, Object>();

    public ContactPostBack() {}

    public ContactPostBack(
        String url, Map<String, String> headers, Map<String, Object> contact
    ) {
        this.url = url;
        this.headers = headers;
        this.contact = contact;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }
    public void addHeader(String key, String value) {
        this.headers.put(key, value);
    }
    public void addField(String key, Object value) {
        this.contact.put(key, value);
    }
    public Map<String, Object> getContact() {
        return this.contact;
    }
}
```

The actual ContactController2 class creates the List:

```java
global class ContactController2 {

    private final Contact contact;
    private List<ContactPostBack> pbcList = new List<ContactPostBack>();
        
    public ContactController2(ApexPages.StandardController sc) {
        this.contact = (Contact)sc.getRecord();
        
        // Logic to initialize class...
        this.setData();
    }

    public String getContacts() {
        return JSON.serialize(pbcList);
    }

    public void setData() {
        // Business logic to add Contacts to pbcList
        ContactPostBack pbc = new ContactPostBack();
        // ...
        this.pbcList.add(pbc);
    }

}
```

Apex Trigger callout to POST to external API. This is where the error is thrown!!!

```java
global class ContactPostBackController {

    @future (callout=true)
    public static void postContactChanges(String contacts) {
        // Receives the JSON serialized List<ContactPostBack> from the ContactController2
        postIt(contacts);
    }

    private static void postIt(String serializedContacts) {
        // Define request, response, and http objects
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
        Http http = new Http();
        
        // THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR IS THROWN
        List<ContactPostBack> contacts = (List<ContactPostBack>)JSON.deserialize(
            serializedContacts, List<ContactPostBack>.class
        );

        // Logic for sending contact to post back...
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please **[edit]** your post to share the code you used to get the stated error? It is perfectly legitimate and in fact common to deserialize into `Map<String, Object>`.

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! I do not have much experience with serialization/deserialization, but the bottom of the page of the link you provided says that a Map is "*serializable*...only if it uses one of the following data types as a **key**" [emphasis added]. It says nothing of *de*serialization, and it says nothing of the *values* of the Map. Unless you have a different link that states differently, hopefully for you that might not be the issue.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Updated the post! Check it out.

Comment: @Moonpie I ended up realizing that wasn't what I was trying to do, oops! Thanks though.

Answer (score 2):

For cases beyond what can be supported with `JSON.deserialize`, consider using `JSON.deserializeUntyped`. This mode is slightly more complicated, as it returns an `Object` that can be a `List<Object>` (if the JSON starts with `[`), or a `Map<String, Object>` (if the string starts with `{`). This can only return `String`, `Boolean`, `Decimal`, `List<Object>` and `Map<String, Object>` types, though (no automatic parsing of Dates, for example), but will always produce a valid return value assuming the JSON is itself valid.

As a hypothetical example, you can get the data you specify here from code like the following:

```
Map<String, Object> jsonResult = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(jsonString);
String url = (String)jsonResult.get('url');
Map<String, Object> headers = (Map<String, Object>)jsonResult.get('headers');
Map<String, Object> contact = (Map<String, Object>)jsonResult.get('contact');
```

Note that due to a [type-casting bug](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/106068/apex-string-instanceof-object), you can't cast `headers` to a `Map<String, String>`, even though it should work logically, so you'll have a bit of extra code for casting values and so on, but this works reasonably well for most complicated JSON structures.

Comment: And `List<Object>`, ostensibly.

Comment: @AdrianLarson `List<String>` was a major typo. I did mean `List<Object>`, thanks for the catch.

Comment: Wouldn't any `List<Primitive>` be supported in addition to `List<Object>`?

Comment: @AdrianLarson It doesn't do any type sniffing to see if it can return a more optimized list. It will always return exactly one of those types (and null, of course, which isn't really a type).