# Can I Convert Map<String,sobject> to Map<String,object>

Tags: map, sobject, object, convert

I have Data in `MAP<String,sobject>` type map and I wants to put it in `Map<String,object>` type Map. Please help with this casting.

Comment: What have tried? Can you share, with an [edit], what code you currently have even if it doesn't work?

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you can just write:

```
Map<String, Object> widerMap = new Map<String, sObject>();
```

No casting is required to make this work. However, this is due to a [bug](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/106068/2984) in the compiler. If you use this technique, be very careful not to try and store an invalid data type in the value, or you'll get a runtime exception.