# Passing list of concrete objects to method with parameter of list<sObject>

Tags: apex

Is it possible to pass a concrete list of objects into a method that expects a list of sObjects?

E.g.

```
list<account> accs = [select id, name from account];
PassToMethod(accs);
...

public void PassToMethod(list<sObject> objects){
...
}
```

In my particular case I want a generic method that accepts Database.UpsertResult[] + list of sObjects that were upserted.  The method will then capture information (id, name) regarding any upserts that failed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is perfectly legal in Apex.

Answer (score 0):

For things like this, it's usually faster to just give it a try yourself.

Yes it is possible, because:

- You're using a `List`
- `Account` inherits from `SObject`
- You're effectively up-casting (going from a concrete type to a more generic type)

It'd also be possible with a `Map<Id, Account>` (if your method took a `Map<Id, SObject>`), as long as the type of the map's key is the same and the value types are compatible. It's not possible with a `Set<Account>` (if your method took a `Set<SObject>`) though.

There are also some circumstances where you can down-cast (from a generic type to a concrete type), though there are additional restrictions on when down-casting is possible.

Comment: Sort of. [Types are kind of broken](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/125891/2984), but this behavior works because it was specifically built in to the language. sObjects, and their related collections, are special compared to Object and its related collections.