# Is Typecasting of Decimal to String possible in salesforce

Tags: apex

while following the best practices I got to know that while fetching generic sobject fields we should typecast the values so please refer the below code where I was trying to type cast to string and I got an error:

```
List<Sobject> accnt = [SELECT ID,Name,AnnualRevenue FROM Account WHERE Rating IN ('Hot','Cold')];
For(Sobject a : accnt){
    System.debug((String)a.get('Name')+' '+(String)a.get('AnnualRevenue'));
}
```

Error:

> Line: 3, Column: 1 System.TypeException: Invalid conversion from
> runtime type Decimal to String

**Annual revenue is a currency field which returns decimal values. So, could anyone explain why it is giving me an error while typecasting decimal to string?**
Note - >I Know that I can avoid typecasting here in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `+` is used to add two numbers together, and to concatenate String values. When you use a non-string next to a String, `toString()` will be called on the object. As such, you can simply say:

```
System.debug(a.get('Name')+' '+a.get('AnnualRevenue'));
```

You can't directly cast a non-String to a string, as the following is also an error:

```
String output = (String)1.23;
```

But you can use the `+` operator with a string on either side:

```
String output = ''+1.23;
```

```
String output = 1.23+'';
```

I often use this as a quick technique to convert most primitives to a String.

You can only use typecasting between compatible types, like a `Decimal` to an `Integer` (with precision loss) or a `String` to an `Id`.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox,
Could also please let me know which are the other compatible types for type casting other than what you have mentioned in your answer?

Comment: @SaiBhargav There are three basic typecasts for primitives: numeric values (Integer, Decimal, Long, Double), dates (Date, DateTime), and Strings (String, Id). You can also typecast between compatible collection types (sometimes, see [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/106068/2984)), as well as user-defined classes and interfaces. For most other type conversions, you'll use the appropriate `valueOf` methods, most of which don't accept null values as a parameter.

Comment: Thanks a lot! for the explanation

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid typecasting here. As it is not required here. Even if you want to typecast you could use String.valueOf(a.get('AnnualRevenue'))

Comment: Thanks Mukul,
But I Know that I can avoid type casting here. Posted this question so i could know on how to type cast in this situation if I want to. Also String.ValueOf() Doesn't take object as parameter and a.get('AnnualRevenue') will return an object(I have already tried that as well).